# Cancel cursor re-positioning and keep the current cursor position in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to disable cursor positioning for the first several characters in `EditText`.

I have extended `EditText` to implement `onSelectionChanged()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onSelectionChanged(int start, int end) {

    text = this.getText();
    if (text != null) {
        if (start < NUM_FRONT_CHARACTERS || end < NUM_FRONT_CHARACTERS) {

            // Moves the cursor to the end
            setSelection(text.length(), text.length());

            return;
        }
    }

    super.onSelectionChanged(start, end);
}
```

How do I just **cancel** cursor re-positioning, instead of moving the cursor to the end of `EditText`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't override `onSelectionChanged()`, this is too late and is the reason you have to resort to setting the selection again to the end of the text. Override `setSelection()` instead and only call through to `super.setSelection()` if your condition holds. Note there are two methods for setting the selection that you must override:

```
@Overrride
public void setSelection(int index) {
    if (index >= NUM_FRONT_CHARACTERS) {
        super.setSelection(index);
    }
}

@Overrride
public void setSelection(int start, int end) {
    if (start >= NUM_FRONT_CHARACTERS && end >= NUM_FRONT_CHARACTERS) {
        super.setSelection(start, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: I overrode both functions but the cursor position moves around freely. am I doing something wrong?